# Grails multiple datasource, not working when trying to save a new Instance into selected datasource

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I'm having this issue with a simple configuration when working with multiple datasources and I'm trying to save a new instance into a specific datasource

my datasources:

```
dataSources:
    dataSource:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
        driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        username: root
        password: Choice2016
    dominio1:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
        driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        username: root
        password: Choice2016
    dominio2:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
        driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        username: root
        password: Choice2016
```

my domain

```
class Nxtt_reports {

    Boolean favorite

    static hasMany = [nxtt_report_histories: Nxtt_report_history, nxtt_user_reports: Nxtt_user_reports, nxtt_report_snapshots: Nxtt_report_snapshot]

    static constraints = {

    }

    static mapping = {
        datasource 'ALL'
    }

}
```

when I do this,

```
    def nxtt = Nxtt_reports.class
    println(nxtt.dominio1.list())
```

I can list data in the domain I want, but if I do this

```
    def nxtt = Nxtt_reports.class.newInstance()
    nxtt.favorite = 0
    nxtt.dominio2.save()
```

I'm getting this

No such property: dominio2 for class: nexttreport.server.Nxtt_reports. Stacktrace follows:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: dominio2 for class: nexttreport.server.Nxtt_reports

using:

| Grails Version: 3.1.1
| Groovy Version: 2.4.5
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_65

edit

```
environments:
    development:
        dataSources:
            dataSource:
                dbCreate: update
                url: jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.24:3306/nexttreport?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false
            dominio1:
                dbCreate: update
                url: jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.24:3306/dominio1?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false
            dominio2:
                dbCreate: update
                url: jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.24:3306/dominio2?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false
```

Comment: Can you update the post and add your environments datasource configuration?

Comment: yes, I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I have a bit of trouble reading a and understanding your code, because you are not following normal Java/Groovy conventions.

Firstly I would recommend using normal CamelCase and no underscores in your class names, so use `NxxtReports`.

Secondly, why not do `NxxtReports.domino1.list()` ?
`list()` is a static method on the `NxxtReports`, so call it like that.

Thirdly and I think most importantly, use the normal Java/Groovy way of instantiating an Object, so do

```
def nxxt = new NxxtReport()
nxxt.favorite = 0
nxxt.domino2.save()
```

I suspect that the extra Grails methods on a DomainClass instance are not correctly added by calling `newInstance()` on the `class` variable.

I don't have a real computer at hand (on mobile now) so I can't check my code, but I think using normal Java/Groovy conventions will help a lot.